# jQuery check is letter is available in the array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, string

I still have a problem with jQuery code.

I want to check characters from strings which is in array while user typing something in the input. If any of first one characters is available in the array i want to display "VALID".

```
var postcodes = ["00-240","80","32","90","91", "8", "11"];

    $('input[name="text-391"]').keyup(function(){
        var val = this.value;
        var m =  $.map(postcodes,function(value,index){
           var reg = new RegExp('^'+val+'.*$')
           return value.match(reg);
        });
        if(m.length && val.length) {
          $('#error').hide(300);
        } else {
          $('#error').show(300);
        }
    });
```

This code checks that all what user type in the input is in array, but i want to check this letter after letter.

For example:

user types: 0 - it's ok

user types: 00 - it's still ok

user types 00-340 - it's not ok and now I want to display warning that we haven't it in the array

user types: 3 - it's ok

user types: 35 - it's not ok, and now i want to display warning that we haven't it in the array

user types 80-125 - it's still ok **[important]**

user types 11-1 - it's still ok **[important]**

I will be very grateful for any tips. Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add below code in `$.map`

```
if(val.length>2 && val.indexOf("-")>-1 && !(value.indexOf("-")>-1))
        val= val.substring(0,val.indexOf("-"))
```

Here is the working [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/hemojixi/1/edit?html,js,output)

Explanation:

You just want to check if enter value length is more than two and it contains `-` and value in map should not contain `-`(you need last and condition for letter like "xx-xxx"

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to check it both ways:

```
   var m =  $.map(postcodes,function(value,index){
       var reg = new RegExp('^'+val+'.*$')
       var result=value.match(reg);
       if (result.length) {
           return result;
       } else {
           reg = new RegExp('^'+value+'.*$')
           return val.match(reg);
       }
   });
```

You can optimize further if you first create an array of regex's based on postcodes and then reference them by index in the callback function.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't understand what i have here.